# Cómo agrupar un array de objetos por valor para un mismo item?

Tags: javascript, json, array, reactjs, table

Tengo una duda, cómo puedo hacer para mapear y reducir un array como este:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Price: 50,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Price: 100,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: {id: 2, Start: "202002"}
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        Price: 200,
        Item: {id: 2, Name: "B"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
    }
]
```

Estoy escribiendo una app en React y quiero mostrar esos valores agrupados en una tabla.

Tendría que quedar algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera poder hacer esto con el array:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: [{id: 1, Start: "202001",Price: "50"},{id: 2, Start: "202002",Price: "100"}]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Item: {id: 2, Name: "B"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001",Price: "200"}
    }
]
```

Alguna sugerencia para llegar a lo que necesito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con:

```js
const original = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Price: 50,
    Item: { id: 1, Name: 'A' },
    Date: { id: 1, Start: '202001' },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Price: 100,
    Item: { id: 1, Name: 'A' },
    Date: { id: 2, Start: '202002' },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Price: 200,
    Item: { id: 2, Name: 'B' },
    Date: { id: 1, Start: '202001' },
  },
];
let modified = [];

original.forEach(({Price, Item, Date}) => {
  const dateWithPrice = { ...Date, Price: Price };
  let existingItem = modified.find(({id}) => id == Item.id);
  if (existingItem) {
    existingItem.Date.push(dateWithPrice);
  } else {
    modified.push({id: Item.id, Item: Item, Date: [dateWithPrice]});
  }
});
console.log(modified);
```

No lo especificaste explícitamente, pero incluí el id del item como elemento `id` del objeto principal Si ese `id` fuese otro, ahí queda a tu criterio cambiarlo.

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias! Buscaba ordenar el array así, para facilitar el recorrido y mostrar los datos. Cuál es la mejor manera de recorrerlo y mostrar los valores como están en la tabla?

Comment: Lo que mencionas ya corresponde a otra pregunta, no lo que preguntaste aquí. Te sugiero realizar otra pregunta donde especifiques eso, además de incluir el código relevante de cómo estás generando esa tabla, así quizás otr@s más puedan contestar tus dudas aparte de mí. Y recuerda que si con mi respuesta contesté tu duda, considera marcarla como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: Gracias! Haré lo que me estás sugiriendo.